Multi-line fields and inserting columns
We need to import our passwords from a format that is not explicity understood by Bitwarden.
The old tool exports to CSV, and I've build a simple Python script to change some column names as well as inserting a couple of new columns.  The script I'm using is below:
import os, re, glob
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(glob.glob('accounts_*.csv')[0])
df['collections']=re.sub('folder-', '', os.path.basename(os.getcwd()))
df['type']='login'
result = df.rename(columns={'nickname': 'name', 'additionalInfo': 'notes', 'url': 'login_uri', 'username': 'login_username', 'password': 'login_password', 'twofaSecret': 'login_totp'})
result.to_csv("test.csv")

It's working well except for one issue, each record has a notes field that can span multiple lines, e.g.
nickname,username,password,additionalInfo
Some site,username,PASSWORD,Some website we use
Another site,username2,PASSWORD2,A longer description with a carriage return
And some more text
And more
And more

All the records need the same two extra columns, so I'm adding them this way:
df['collections']='Some Collection'
df['type']='login'
The problem is it adds those columns on the multi-line fields, e.g.
collections,type,name,login_username,login_password,notes
Some Collection,login,username,PASSWORD,Some website we use
Some Collection,login,Another site,A longer description with a carriage return
Some Collection,login,And some more text
Some Collection,login,And more
Some Collection,login,And more

Actually Bitwarden is able to import the file successfully, just every line in the note is prefixed with Some Collection,login,.
I could use regex to remove the unwanted text, but I wondered if I could use pandas in a different way so it didn't recognise every newline as a new record?
Thanks for any tips!

Are the notes fields properly encapsulated by quotes? E.g. "Some website we use", and also: "A longer description with a carriage return\nAnd some more text\nAnd more\nAnd more". If so, you should be able to use import csv and then add pd.read_csv(..., quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL).

From your example, I don't think there's a way to differentiate actual new lines from the notes that span multiple lines when importing the CSV file into pandas. Unless you can export the file with the values encapsulated in quotes, as suggested in the comments.
If you want to solve it with pandas, one option would be to import the CSV as is, group by the values in 'nickname', 'username', 'password', then aggregate by first in all except the last column, where you ''.join all the rows.
Using your example as input:
import io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = """nickname,username,password,additionalInfo
Some site,username,PASSWORD,Some website we use
Another site,username2,PASSWORD2,A longer description with a carriage return
And some more text
And more
And more"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data))

df.loc[df["username"].isna(), "additionalInfo"] = df["nickname"]
df.loc[df["username"].isna(), "nickname"] = np.nan

g = df[["nickname", "username", "password"]].ffill()
df = df.groupby([g["nickname"], g["username"], g["password"]], as_index=False).agg(
    {
        "nickname": "first",
        "username": "first",
        "password": "first",
        "additionalInfo": " ".join,
    }
)

       nickname   username   password                                     additionalInfo
0  Another site  username2  PASSWORD2  A longer description with a carriage return An...
1     Some site   username   PASSWORD                                Some website we use


In the end I discovered that the original export did have double-quotes around the multi-line comments, but not around other text fields.
I had done some other manipulation of the files with Pandas before I tried handling this, which had removed the double-quotes.
After going back to the original file with the quotes, it seemed to handle the file, despite it being slightly inconsistent with quotes..
Thanks for the tips and suggestions though!
